# Single NGINX-Ingress Controller for subdomains that have resources in separate namespaces

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Can anyone explain to me how to set up a **SINGLE** nginx ingress controller with configuration that I currently have, as follows:

- A.MY-SITE.COM = Service, Ingress, Pods..etc live under the "A" namespace
- B.MY-SITE.COM = Service, Ingress, Pods..etc live under the "B" namepsace

I've seen here

https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.7.0/examples-of-custom-resources/cross-namespace-configuration

This seems to be on the right track, but it's for paths "/cafe".  When I need it to be "a.my-site.com".

The main reason I want to do this is I don't want to have to install an ingress controller for every client (namespace) we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured this out,
The default HELM nginx-ingress controller installation works fine without SSL certificates. NGINX Controller actually does work with ingress resources from various namespaces.

I installed my `*.domain.com` certificate and key using

```
kubectl create secret tls {SECRET_NAME} --key {KEY_FILE} --cert {CERT_FILE}
```

Then in the nginx-ingress-controller deployment I added:

```
-args:
 - --default-ssl-certificate=tenancy/whatevername-wildcard={NAMESPACE}/{SECRET_NAME}
```

The ingresses live in the namespace.  For example:

Namespace A: Ingress -> `Host: a.domain.com`

Namespace B: Ingress with `host: b.domain.com`

the only thing listed in the annotations for the ingress controllers is
`kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

All domains points to the nginx load balancer IP.

Now it works perfectly.  Very simple, but it was also very unclear scouring through the docs.